# Why my Feature Class created with the tool "create feature from XY table" is outside the Feature Dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, feature-class, feature-dataset

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2 and I'm trying to create a Feature Class inside a Feature Dataset from a table opened through OLE-DB connection using the tool "Create Feature Class from XY Table". 
The output Feature Dataset Coordinate System is the same than the Feature Class I want to create (WGS 1984), and , when I run the tool, I don't get any error message.
But the output feature class is created OUTSIDE the Feature Dataset!!
(Still inside the File Geodatabase, but outside the desired Feature Dataset). 
Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how I could avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

When creating a feature class from a table (or a text file), you cannot export directly into a feature dataset; this is just an existing limitation of the software. but there could be a good reason behind it.

The recommended workaround is to use the Make XY Event Layer GP tool first and then exporting the event layer into a feature class within the feature dataset; this is supported.